# Cant understand relationship eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I want to select something like this from my users table:

```
select name from users where room.user1_id = user.id
```

My idea is to have two users in one room. In my User model  i have these:

```
public function room(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Room', 'user1_id');
}
```

In room model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

I tried to call like this in controller:

```
$room = Room::find($room_id);
return $room->user->name;
```

Here is an example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42l4nHl_aUM
```

at: 9:05

so this returns this error:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.room_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from`users`where`users`.`room_id`= 8 and`users`.`room_id`is not null`)

Comment: If one room has many users then it should be like this in Room Model  `public function users(){ return $this->hasMany('App\User'); }` this will return you collection of users.

Comment: You will return all the user's name of a room by this `$room->users->pluck('name');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is backwards between rooms and users.

Change your User model to:

```
public function room(){
    return $this->hasOne(App\Room::class, 'user1_id');
}
```

and Room model to:

```
public function user1 (){
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'user1_id');
}

public function user2 (){
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'user2_id');
}
```

However, if user(s) could be assigned rooms in the future for difference events, reservations, etc. it would be better to create a pivot table and use a many-to-many relationship. Convention would have it named `room_user` and defined in a migration as:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('room_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

$table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Then your model relationships would change to:

```
// User.php
public function rooms (){
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Room::class);
}

// Room.php
public function users (){
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class);
}
```

Any additional constraints could be later applied through a query scope or filtering of the resultant collection.

Comment: Made my day thanks :)
return $this->hasOne(App\Room::class, 'user1_id'); this was not working but this was working:
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');